# Comparison of arbitary conway chains (in particular a chain with $m$ $m's$) to $f_{\omega^2}(n)$

Tags: number-theory, functions, big-numbers

Wikipedia describes the [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) and the [fast growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy).

I learnt that the function $f(n):=\large f_{\omega^2}(n)$ has the same growth rate as the
function $g(n):=n\rightarrow n\rightarrow n\rightarrow ... \rightarrow n\rightarrow n$ with $n\ n's$ in the chain.

- But how can I concretely compare a number $f(m)$ to a number $g(n)$ for arbitary natural numbers m,n ?
- How can I compare arbitary conway chains with some value of $f(m)$ ?
- For which natural numbers $n$ does the inequality $g(n)>f(n)$ hold ,
  and for which $f(n)>g(n)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have $$f_{\omega a+b}(c) \approx \underbrace{3 \rightarrow 3 \cdots 3 \rightarrow 3}_{a+1} \rightarrow c \rightarrow (b+1)$$

Let's evaluate some small numbers. $f(1)=2$, $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=4$  $$g(3)<f(2)=f_{\omega2}(2)=f_{\omega+2}(2)=f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(2))=f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(2))=f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega}(8))\approx3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow (2 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 7) \rightarrow 2 < g(4)$$

$$g(4) < f(3)=f_{\omega3}(3)=f_{\omega2+3}(3)\approx 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 < g(5)$$

$$g(5) < f(4)=f_{\omega4}(4)=f_{\omega3+4}(4)\approx 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 5 < g(6)$$

In general, we have $g(n+1)<f(n)<g(n+2)$ for $n\geq2$. It is fairly hard to formally proof.

$f(n)>g(n)$ holds for all natural $n$. It certainly holds for $n\geq2$, and we also have $f(1)=2>1=g(1)$. In fact it also holds for 0, since $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)$ is empty thus zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never read about the $g(n+1)<f(n)<g(n+2)$ -inequality.

Comment: Did you notice my question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345845/comparing-conway-chains ?

Comment: @Peter No, I didn't. I shall take a look to it tomorrow. I highly suspect the statement to be true, at least for large $a$.

Comment: By your formula, $f_{\omega}(8)\approx 3\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 8$ , why do you use $2\rightarrow 8\rightarrow 7$ the smaller one ?