# Tight bounds for Bowers array notation

Tags: number-theory, functions, big-numbers

This link

http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Array_notation

shows the definition of bowers linear array notation and the approximation
$$\{n,a+1,b+1,c+1,d+1,...\}\ \approx f^a_{...+\omega^2d+\omega c+b}(n)$$

I think for very small entries the approximation is not very tight, so I would
like to know some relatively tight bounds to understand how good the approximation is.

- How big must the entries be, such that the approximation is "well" ? Is the approximation already "well" for $$\underbrace { \{\ 3,...,3 \}\ }_n $$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3 entry arrays the approximation is not very good. It gives $a \uparrow^c b \approx f_{c-1}^b(a)$. The actual result is closer to $a \uparrow^c b \approx f_{c}^b(a)$.

I will actually proof something this time.

Let $a<65536$.

We take $b\geq4$. Note that $f_{2}(f_2(b)) > f_{2}(16b) = 65536^b\cdot 16b > \{a,b\}$.

Therefore $f_{3}(f_3(b)) >  f_{3}(2b) > f_{2}^{2b}(4) > \{a,b,2\}$.

By induction, $f_{c+1}(f_{c+1}(b)) >  f_{c+1}(2b) > f_{c}^{2b}(4) > \{a,b,c\}$.

Then we have $f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4)) >f_{a+1}(2a) > \{a,2,1,2\}=\{a,a,a\}$.

$\{a,3,1,2\}=\{a,a,\{a,a,a\}\}<\{a,a,f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4))\}<f_{f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4))+1}(2a)<f_{f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4)))}(2a)<f_{f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4)))}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4))))=f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(f_{\omega}(4))))$.

By induction again, $\{a,b,1,2\}<f_{\omega+1}(2b)$ for $b\geq2$.

By induction again, $\{a,b,c,2\}<f_{\omega+c}(2b)$ for $b\geq2$.

$\{a,2,1,3\}=\{a,a,a,2\}<f_{\omega+a}(2a)<f_{\omega2}(f_{\omega2}(4))$.

By triple induction, we will get $\{a,b,c,d\}<f_{\omega(d-1)+c}(2b)$.

$\{a,a,a,a\}<f_{\omega3+a}(a)<f_{\omega^2}(f_{\omega^2}(4))$

Induction, $\{a,b,1,1,2\} < f_{\omega^2+1}(b)$

Induction, $\{a,b,c,1,2\} < f_{\omega^2+c}(b)$

$\{a,2,1,2,2\}=\{a,a,a,1,2\}< f_{\omega^2+a}(a)<f_{\omega^2+\omega}(f_{\omega^2+\omega}(4))$

$\{a,b,1,2,2\} < f_{\omega^2+\omega+1}(2b)$

$\{a,b,c,d,2\} < f_{\omega^2+\omega(d-1)+c}(2b)$

$\{a,b,c,d,e\} < f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c}(2b)$.

Now, realize that $$f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c-1}^{2b}(a) \approx f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c-1}^{2b}(2b) =f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c}(2b)$$

Also note that large overestimations have been made. First expanding and then using the proper upper bound actually gives a much better bound.

In general the bound is a good bound for $n\geq3$ and the number of entries > 3.

Note that intuitively, we can replace every $2b$ with $b-1$ to get a lower bound. However we run into some problems when formally proving it. Eg. Estimating $f_3(f_3(b-1)-1)$ formally is very hard.

Comment: Great answer again! Just to clarify : Does the inequality $f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c}(b-1)<[4,b,c,d,e]<f_{\omega^2(e-1)+\omega(d-1)+c}(2b)$ hold for every $b,c,d,e>2$ ? Are there similar bounds for $n\ne 4$ ?

Comment: @Peter The upper bound holds for all $b,c,d,e \geq 1$. The lower bound is like I said, hard to proof, but I'd say it holds for all $b,c,d,e \geq 2$ at least. Nor $n \neq 4$, one can just repeat the proof. One can see that the proof can be modified so that it holds for $2 < n < 16$ at least. But for very large $n$ it must fail as the bound it is not dependent on $n$.

Comment: What about the bounds for $[4,b,c,d]$ ? Which $n$ are allowed here ?

Comment: All bounds work for $n<65536$. For larger $n$ it works for large $b,c,d,e$ only.