# Bowers array notation : $f_{\omega^\omega}(n)\approx [n,...,n]$ ($n$ times)

Tags: number-theory, functions, big-numbers

I learnt at this [site](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) that

$$\large f_{\omega^\omega}(n)\approx \underbrace{[n,...,n]}_{n\ n's}$$

For a simular approximation

$$\large f_{\omega^2}(n)\approx \underbrace{n\rightarrow n\rightarrow...\rightarrow n\rightarrow n}_{n\ n's}\ =:\ g(n)$$

Wythagoras concreted this approximation to the inequality

$$\large g(n+1)<f_{\omega^2}(n)<g(n+2)\ \ for\ \ n\ge 2$$

Is there a similar inequality in this case ?

Comment: @najib didn't you like the underbrace ? And why did you remove the large-relais ?

Comment: It took too much place on the front page. You can add it back in the body of the post (though I don't see the point, if someone isn't happy with the size they can zoom with their browser), but do not add it back to the title.

Comment: I think, underbraces are visually helpful, but I accept your demand not editing back the title.

Comment: I also made things clearer by mentioning that there are $n$ $n's$ in the chain/array.

Comment: If you sign op on Wikia and log in, most of the ads will be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be familiar to you that $f_{\omega}(3)\approx\{3,3,3\}=h(3)$. Similiarly, $f_{\omega^2}(4)\approx\{4,4,4,4\}=h(4)$, and in general $$h(n+1) << f_{\omega^\omega}(n) < h(n+2)$$

for $n \geq 3$. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384308/tight-bounds-for-bowers-array-notation).

Comment: With birds inequality, we have, for example $\large \{ 3,3,3,3,3\}<f_{\omega^3}(3)<\{5,5,5,5,5\}$, but I wonder if $\large \{4,4,4,4,4\}<f_{\omega^3}(3)$ or $\large \{4,4,4,4,4\}>f_{\omega^3}(3)$

Comment: @Peter Note that $\{4,4,4,4,4\} \approx f_{\omega^2 3+\omega 3 + 3}^3(3)$, which is much larger than $f_{\omega^2 3}(3)=f_{\omega^3}(3)$.